# Equivalent statement in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an app in Kotlin and am using the dependency [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView). However, most of their code is written in Java and I am having some troubles converting them to Kotlin. Does anyone know the Kotlin equivalent of this piece of Java code?

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
          new DataPoint(0, 1),
          new DataPoint(1, 5),
          new DataPoint(2, 3),
          new DataPoint(3, 2),
          new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+K` in IntelliJ/Android Studio does that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val graph = findViewById(R.id.graph) as GraphView
val series = LineGraphSeries(arrayOf(
          DataPoint(0, 1),
          DataPoint(1, 5),
          DataPoint(2, 3),
          DataPoint(3, 2),
          DataPoint(4, 6)
     )
)
graph.addSeries(series)
```

but you could order it as

```
val graph: GraphView = findViewById(R.id.graph)

graph.addSeries(LineGraphSeries(arrayOf(
          DataPoint(0, 1),
          DataPoint(1, 5),
          DataPoint(2, 3),
          DataPoint(3, 2),
          DataPoint(4, 6)
     )
))
```